# Catch exception by type using Node.js / promisses

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

There is the following code:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  models.Task.find(req.params.id).then(function(task) {
    return task.updateAttributes({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    });
  }).then(function(task) {
    res.json(task);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    var err = new Error('Cannot find Task');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
  });
});
```

As you can see, I use this route to update Task model by id. So, now I catch the error if there is no task with id and I try to update attributes for null object (ReferenceError error type). So, I've just added validations to Task model and there is an opportunity to update task with empty title/description (SequelizeValidationError error type). How can I process this errors in my catch block? I want to set 'Cannot find Task', 'Cannot update Task' messages for this errors. Should I to split my catch block, or anything else? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Id suggest using bluebird promises instead, see this answer on why http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

Answer (score 1):

If you're not willing to use a library that speeds up and enhances the API of native promises like bluebird, you can build some of the functionality yourself:

```
function errT(type, fn){
    return function(err){ // create a handler for errors
        if(!(err instanceof type)) throw err; // allow fallthrough if it doesn't match
        return fn(err); 
    };
}
```

Or similarly in ES2015 syntax:

```
let errT = (type, fn) => err => (err instanceof type) ? Promise.reject(err) : fn(err);
```

This would let you do, for instance:

```
promiseReturningFn().
  catch(errT(TypeError, handleTypeError)).
  catch(errT(ReferenceError, handleReferenceError));
```

It is warmly recommended that you subclass Error to your own types, provide additional info and catch on those. I find it a very positive practice in my own code and it helps avoid accidentally catching programmer errors (instead of application errors).

Comment: can you provide me with example of using bluebird? For my task

Comment: @malcoauri basically, bluebird does this out of the box, so you can just remove the `errT` around catch and not have to define it (it'll also be faster), so just `promiseReturningFn().catch(TypeError, handleTypeError).catch(ReferenceError, handleReferenceError)` there is also an `.error` built in and a base `OperationalError` type for application errors so you don't accidentally silent programmer errors.